# Is it possible to share a react query `QueryClient` between serverless functions in nextJS?

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel, react-query

We've recently inherited a nextJS project which is making far too many API calls to prismic, and are at threat of being bumped up to an extortionate costing if we don't get on top of it.

One of the main issues is the calling of multiple documents on each page load (header, footer, nav etc).

As the other calls on the site make use of React-Query to prefetch and hydrate data, we thought it would be a good idea to add prismic data to the cache.

However... since we fetch this data purely serverside, we won't be able to take advantage of react-query without some form of shared serverside querycache.

This leads me to my question,
Is it valid to keep some sort of `prefetchQueryClient` defined in a const and shared between server functions, this way we can check serverside if the client already has (non-stale) data, and only pre-fetch if it doesnt.

Is this some sort of anti-pattern? Is there a nicer workaround in next/vercel which will achieve the same end result?